# Why Netezza Sequence giving same value for two different keys

Tags: netezza

I am generating seq_id  using Netezza sequence. The key is generated based on the unique combination of columns  A,B but I am facing the issue that for two different unique combination I am getting same sequence id . Can you please help me with his .

```
SEQ_ID A, B
8000   1,2
8000   3,4
9000   1,8 
1000   7,9
```

Query  used

```
SELECT                                                                      
        NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_A_B_ID AS  SEQ_ID     ,
        A.A ,                                                       
        A.B
        FROM(
              SELECT DISTINCT A , B FROM TABLE1 
              where A|| '-' || B NOT IN (SELECT A || '-' || B FROM  TABLE12)
                )  A   
;
```

Sequence Definition

```
CREATE SEQUENCE DSADM.SEQ_A_B_ID AS BIGINT  
START WITH 5476300001  
INCREMENT BY 1  
NO MINVALUE   
NO MAXVALUE   
NO CYCLE;
```

Thanks,

Sorry I added test data,  the actual data look likes as follows

```
5488310365  3099505744582340000 5305804635993960000  
5488310365  3094070450584350000 6702650425474680000
```

and the output of `SELECT * FROM DSADM.SEQ_A_B_ID`   is

```
SEQUENCE_NAME: SEQ_A_B_ID       
LAST_VALUE: 5476300001  
INCREMENT_BY: 1  
MAX_VALUE: 9223372036854780000  
MIN_VALUE:1  
CACHE_VALUE: 100000  
LOG_CNT:1  
IS_CYCLED:FALSE  
IS_CALLED:FALSE  
DATATYPE:20
```

Comment: Can you also provide the definition of your sequence?

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  it seems odd that your sample data would be providing sequence numbers in round 1000s with that sequence definition.  Normally each SPU will have about 100,000 sequence values cached out.  Assuming all of your sample is not actually only located on one SPU, that cache size can't be anything over 1000.  Would you also please provide the output of  this command: SELECT * FROM DSADM."^SEQ_A_B_ID^

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduces this, and I can't think of any situation where a Sequence that doesn't CYCLE would produce duplicate values. Wracked my brain on this one, but sadly I'm coming up empty.  I'd recommend opening a case with support.